# How to check control.anchor property value in C#?

Tags: c#, anchor

How do you check the value of a control's anchor property?

Suppose I have a control which the code developer can set the anchor values in the designer. In C# code, how do I check if any particular anchor value is set for the control?

For example, suppose the Sender control below has it's Top, Left, and Right anchors set by a developer for this control. What is the if statement like to check that the Top anchor is set?

```
private int DetermineMouseWhere(Control Sender)
{
    if (Sender.Anchor == AnchorStyles.Top) // what should this be like
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Some of you may be tempted to ask why you might want to do this... I do not want to provide resizing operations on this control if the anchor is set on that side of the control.

Answer (score 5):

Because AnchorStyles has the [Flags] attribute, you can use the [Enum.HasFlag()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method to determine it:

```
if (Sender.Anchor.HasFlag(AnchorStyles.Top))
```

For .Net 3.5 or earlier:

```
if ((Sender.Anchor & AnchorStyles.Top) != 0)
```

Or:

```
if ((Sender.Anchor & AnchorStyles.Top) == AnchorStyles.Top)
```

Comment: This will only with framework versions 4+, and can be slower than a manual bit check.

Comment: *Will* be much slower than a manual bit check. But we're talking microseconds, and it's (probably) not in an inner loop, so code clarity takes precedence. :) Still, I have added the & code.

Comment: _Well_, **not** if you do all the things `HasFlag` does.

Comment: I love the way you edit your answer to aggregate other answers as they're added :)

Comment: Grrr. I didn't even look at the other answers! I was just responding to Grant's comments. After all, there's only 2 ways to do it. It's hardly surprising that the answers might be the same... :)

Comment: Thanks everyone! I had a hard time finding the right words to enter into google to get help. Hopefully your response will get picked up and put at the top of the list for control.anchor. Also, I hope for the future that Microsoft gives more relevant examples.

Comment: @John Well you could - you know - accept the answer you think is most appropriate, if you're really grateful ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since Enum.HasFlag() is only supported since .NET 4, here's a way that'll work with earlier versions:

```
if (Sender.Anchor & AnchorStyles.Top != 0)
```

For multiple anchors (such as Top-Left)

```
if (Sender.Anchor & (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left) == (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left))
```

If you're going to check many times over, you might want to implement a method for that.

```
public bool StyleHasOptions(AnchorStyles style, AnchorStyles options)
{
    return style & options == options;
}

//// Use it like this:
// if (StyleHasOptions(Sender.Anchor, AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left))
```

Comment: For multiple anchor checking, this is shorter: if ((Sender.Anchor & (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left)) != 0)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Unforntunately, it is also wrong (that's what I wrote originally, until I noticed what I did wrong). If your `Anchor` is `Top` only, `&` will result in `Top`, which is `!= 0`, but it's not really what we're expecting. We want both `Top` and `Left` to be set.

Comment: Ah yes, I was checking for either to be set, not both!

Answer (score 2):

checking for flags set is usually done like this:

```
if ((Sender.Anchor & Anchor.Styles.Top) == Anchor.Styles.Top)
    //do something
```